Unable to retrieve data from postgres json column
I have a postgres table with json column as dataset_metadata. It stores an epoc time in array looks like:
select 
 event_type
,technology
,dataset_metadata->> 'intervals_epoch_seconds'
,add_ts from fact_completeness_count_requests;

when I run above, I am getting this:
    event_type    | technology |                                                 ?column?                                                 |           add_ts
------------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------
 INGESTED_DATASET | USPP       | [[1720707300, 1720708200], [1720708200, 1720709100], [1720709100, 1720710000], [1720706400, 1720707300]] | 2024-08-08 04:28:13.3942
 INGESTED_DATASET | PLTE       | [[1720287900, 1720288800]]                                                                               | 2024-08-08 04:29:24.786225
 INGESTED_DATASET | LTE        | [[1720711800, 1720712700]]

I want that it should return the min and max epoc time from a given row and convert it into date and display it in separate column:
select to_timestamp(1720711800);


pm-cm-state=> \d fact_completeness_count_requests
                    Table "public.fact_completeness_count_requests"
         Column          |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 event_type              | character varying(255)      |           | not null |
 technology              | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 dataset_metadata        | json                        |           | not null |

we are using postgres version PostgreSQL 9.6

Please provide your table definition and sample data as SQL commands, so we can easily recreate your case: CREATE TABLE, INSERT. And always disclose your Postgres version.

You want to unnest multiple JSON array dimensions (before converting).
A simple and safe solution is trickier than it might seem.
For a maximum of two array dimensions:
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT to_timestamp(min((a.ts #>> '{}')::float)) AS min_ts
        , to_timestamp(max((a.ts #>> '{}')::float)) AS max_ts
   FROM   jsonb_path_query(t.data->'intervals_epoch_seconds', '$[*][*]') a(ts)
   WHERE  t.data->'intervals_epoch_seconds' IS JSON ARRAY            -- may or may not be necessary; requires pg 16+
-- WHERE  jsonb_typeof(t.data->'intervals_epoch_seconds') = 'array'  -- fallback for pg 15-
   ) j;

fiddle
jsonb_path_query requires Postgres 12 or later.
... IS JSON ARRAY` requires Postgres 16 or later. (I provided a fallback.)
See:

jsonb_array_elements() fails with "ERROR: cannot extract elements from an object"
Find rows containing a key in a JSONB array of records

To note, a normalized relational design instead of the nested JSON array would be simpler and faster.

We are using PostgreSQL 9.6 version and getting error message when running below query

SELECT *
FROM   fact_completeness_count_requests t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
SELECT to_timestamp(min((a.ts #>> '{}')::float)) AS min_ts
, to_timestamp(max((a.ts #>> '{}')::float)) AS max_ts
FROM   jsonb_path_query(t.dataset_metadata->'intervals_epoch_seconds', '$[][]') a(ts)
WHERE  jsonb_typeof(t.dataset_metadata->>'intervals_epoch_seconds') = 'array'
) j;
ERROR:  function jsonb_path_query(json, unknown) does not exist
LINE 6:    FROM   jsonb_path_query(t.dataset_metadata->'intervals_ep...
^

Postgres 9.6 is hopelessly outdated - unsupported since 2021. See: https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ I added version info. Please always declare your version of Postgres in your question right away.
